# Using an Enumerator instead of loops

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I usually use `loop` as below to request data form an external API or DB (redis pop):

```
records = []
loop do
  record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch
  break unless record
  records.push(record)
end
```

It works, but to make it look better, I wonder whether there is any way to use an `Enumerator`. Does anyone know one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping your code in an [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html) is quite easy:

```
record_enumerator = Enumerator.new do |y|
  loop do
    record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch
    break unless record
    y << record
  end
end
```

You can now iterate over the records using a block:

```
record_enumerator.each { |record|
   # do something with record
}
```

Or fetch all records with:

```
records = record_enumerator.to_a
```

If `MyHandler` is your class, you could implement `MyHandler#each` instead and include [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html).

Comment: Custom `Enumerator` classes can help clean up your code considerably. This is a great example.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
while(record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch)
  records.push(record)
end
```

That gets rid of the ugly loop/break logic.

Alternatively, you could create an ennumerable object instead of using the records array:

```
class RecordList
  include Enumerable

  attr :token

  def initialize(token)
    @token = token
  end

  def each
    MyHandler.new(token).fetch
  end
end

records = RecordList.new token
```

Comment: I think while(record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch) breaks CQS principle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loops in ruby like so:

```
records = []
record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch
while record do
    records << record
    record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch
end
```

There might be an even more elegent way, but from the information provided, that's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the really short syntax, here you go:

```
records << record while record = MyHandler.new(token).fetch
```

It will work like a charm, the condition check is done *before* executing the loop body, hence record is always initialized.